# Map of user locations?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, users

Maybe this has been brought up before and I'm not finding it, but is it just me, or is almost crazy for this site (or dare I say *all* SE sites) to not have some sort of map of user locations? Not one of those cheezy ones you see on old-skool forums where it maps your IP address and puts a little flashing dot where it thinks you might be, but something based on modern, open API (like determining which one to use wouldn't start a holy war, huh?). Users have the option of adding their location in their profile, and if I remember correctly, it even validates it for you, right? That location could then be used to put them on the map. Thoughts from the SE team on this?

Comment: Needs to be a opt-in option for users.

Comment: @mapperz - agreed, however, they are already putting the info out there textually in their profile.

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, you opted in when you placed your location information in the location field in the profile information. I have created some code to scrape the location field (in Python) and it is accessible [here](http://scraperwiki.com/scrapers/scraping_stackexchange/). (As a note, feel free to update the code to your hearts content)

I'm pretty sure this data is already acessible from the [data dump](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/creative-commons-data-dump-jun-11/) anyway. You could download that information and make maps to your hearts content (and use other information as well).

Although I wouldn't mind to see a feature like this, I would think users on this site would be able to whip up some pretty cool maps on their own.

Answer (score 2):

Location already exists in the profile, and is cross-referenced using the [Yahoo Placefinder API](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/).

We already went through all profiles on the network and auto-mapped the ones we could.

[Location in profile was changed without edit or knowing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88217/location-in-profile-was-changed-without-edit-or-knowing/88220#88220)

Assuming you enter something it can parse, there is a hidden field that contains the coordinates. You can of course enter "The Moon", too, it's just a text field.

Comment: Gotcha, but what about having a actual map of all user locations (pins on a Google map), using that hidden field that contains the coordinate? User can opt out of being on map.